# Coloring not colored text in Bash

Tags: bash, text, colors, sed, grep

I have to colorize some words in the text, that works good, but I have a problem when its already colored. When its colored I dont want to colour it again with different color. My problem is that my code color it again even if it is already colored.

Here is my code:

```
var=$(echo -e $line | grep ".*[^m]${word}[^\][^e].*" | sed -e "s/${word}/${color}${word}${endColor}/g")
if(var -n);then
line=$var
f
```

---

Its a script where is every odd the color and even is word you want to color. The problem is when there is a word that is already colored and I dont want to recolore it.
Input could be anything

here is full code

```
function GetColor {
if [ $1 == 'r' ];then
color=$red;
fi
if [ $1 == 'b' ];then
color=$blue;
fi
if [ $1 == 'g' ];then
color=$green;
fi
}

red=$'\e[31m'
green=$'\e[32m'
blue=$'\e[34m'
endColor=$'\e[0m'
a=0
color=""
word=""
while read input
do
radek=$input
for i in $*; do
if (( a% 2 )); then
word=$i
var=$(echo -e $line | grep ".*[^m]${word}[^\][^e].*" | sed -e "s/${word}/${color}${word}${endColor}/g")
if(var -n);then
line=$var
fi
else
color=""
GetColor "$i"

fi
let "a += 1"
done

echo -e $line
exit
done
```

thanks for help

Comment: please give us some sample data to work with. What is a typical value for $line? Best to also include required output, given the sample input. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is my version, but I've just made the script run without errors.  I'm not sure what the problem is, but the colour of already coloured words are not changed.

I suspect

```
if(var -n);then
```

I corrected it to

```
  if [ -n "$var" ]; then
```

Here's the script

```
function GetColor {
if [ $1 == 'r' ];then
color=$red;
fi
if [ $1 == 'b' ];then
color=$blue;
fi
if [ $1 == 'g' ];then
color=$green;
fi
}

red=$'\e[31m'
green=$'\e[32m'
blue=$'\e[34m'
endColor=$'\e[0m'
a=0
color=""
word=""
while read input
do
  line=$input
  for i in $*; do
    if (( a% 2 )); then
      word=$i
      var=$(echo -e $line | grep ".*[^m]${word}[^\][^e].*" | sed -e "s/${word}/${color}${word}${endColor}/g")
      if [ -n "$var" ]; then
        line=$var
      fi
    else
      color=""
      GetColor "$i"
    fi
    let "a += 1"
  done

  echo -e $line
  exit
done
```