# Bash: how to find and color some text?

Tags: bash, grep

Let's suppose i have this text in bash:

text="Hello world. I am happy guy."

I need to find 2 words: "world", which will have blue color and "guy", which will have red color.
And after this, I need to print all the text on output.
Output:
Hello *world*. I am happy *guy*.

How can i do it please?
Thanks a lot for your time :]

Comment: Does it have to be in Bash?  It might be clearer to do it in e.g. Python or sed.

Comment: Yes, it does.. :( It's my homework.

Comment: i have already found it :D Some guys have solved it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196419/coloring-not-colored-text-in-bash?rq=1). However thank you verz much John Zwinck :]

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk '{gsub($2,"\033[1;34m&\033[0m");gsub($NF,"\033[1;31m&\033[0m")}1' file
Hello world. I am happy guy.
```

It will change second world to `blue` and last word to `red`
You can change the color looking at `ansi` table.
You did not tell how you would like to find the words.